# Talend - How to output JSON records in multiple rows

Tags: json, etl, talend

I have generated a JSON output using Talend. However, my problem is that all my records are outputed in 1 row in the JSON file. Below is the sample output:

```
[{"field1":"value1_1","field2":"value2_1","field3":"value3_1"},{"field1":"value1_2","field2":"value2_2","field3":"value3_2"},{"field1":"value1_3","field2":"value2_3","field3":"value3_3"}]
```

My desired output is to have all JSON record separated by newline in the output file:

```
[{"field1":"value1_1","field2":"value2_1","field3":"value3_1"},
{"field1":"value1_2","field2":"value2_2","field3":"value3_2"},
{"field1":"value1_3","field2":"value2_3","field3":"value3_3"}]
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Being a curious person and all, I have to ask, why do want to achieve this, how will it help you?

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do it, but if it's necessary you can re-read the file as raw file using a `tFileInputRaw` component then replace all `},{` by `},\n{` in a `tJavaRow` component.

Comment: Hi, 

How do I re-read the file as raw file using tJavaRow component?

Comment: @DanielLee Updated answer !

Answer (score 0):

Use the **tFileOutputJSON** component, which will help collect the rows as a list into JSON file. You may then use a tFileInput Component to read it and send it as Response.

Comment: It seems more like a comment. Provide some explanation to your answer.